# Joining all the elements in an NSMutableArray to form an NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray of NSString objects. How would I make an NSString that consists of all the elements in that array joined together with semicolons in between?

For example:

```
array = "hello","hi","bye",nil;
output = "hello;hi;bye";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello", @"hi", @"bye", nil];
NSString *output = [array componentsJoinedByString:@";"];
```